# Is it possible to change the name of a self hosted integration runtime node in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

As the title suggests, I would like to change the name of the self hosted integration runtime node in Azure Data Factory. By default, it is some very generic name, I would like to change it to the name of the VM that hosts the node. Is it possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twTTL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently based on my knowledge it is not possible to rename an existing IR which is already configured:

[image]

The most easy way would be the delete the IR, create a new one new name and reconfigure the IR in the VM with the new keys

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question!
So if we deploy our ADF using terraform, we can assign the name in the resource block that manages self hosted integration runtime?

Comment: Hey @rookie123,
I am not much more aware w.r.t terraform, but once you extract the ARM template from ADF from lower environment and deploy into upper environment ; the new IRs names would be created.
But then the next steps would be to copy the keys from that newly created IR names and install the integration runtime in the actual VM which should happen.

Comment: Oh, okay. Yes the registration part i.e install the IR on the VM I understand it's this name changing that I was confused by. I think I have everything I need from your answer & reply. Thank you very much. I will try to delete the IR, recreate it with the VM's name, install the IR and see if it works. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hey @rookie123,
Can you please mark it as answer as it might help the other community members as well